# state not updating with setState react

Tags: reactjs, components, state, setstate

thanks in advance for taking a look my questions.  So I am POSTing to a DB from the CreateItem component via the submitItem function, then when the promise is returned, I call a pullAllItems to GET all rows for the categories table of my DB to update the state of categories:

React Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CreateItem from './components/CreateItem';
import Categories from './components/Categories';

// stylesheets
import './stylesheets/App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      categories: [],
      tasks: []
    };

    this.submitItem = this.submitItem.bind(this);
    this.pullAllItems = this.pullAllItems.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    fetch('/api/categories')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          categories: res
        });
      });
  }

  submitItem(title) {
    const category = {
      title
    }

    fetch('/api/categories', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(category),
      headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
    }).then(this.pullAllItems('categories'));
  }

  pullAllItems(type) {
    const key = type;
    let obj = {};

    fetch('/api/' + type)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        obj[key] = res;
        this.setState({
          obj
        }, () => {
          console.log(this.state.categories);
        });
      });
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <CreateItem submitItem={this.submitItem} />
        <Categories categories={this.state.categories} pullAllTasks={this.pullAllItems}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

If I console log the response, I get the additional row that was POSTed with the submitItem function; however, when I update the state of categories in my pullAllItems function, the state does not update (even in the callback function of setState).  I am new to react, and have looked everywhere I can to see what I am missing, but can't get a clear-cut answer anywhere.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: In `pullAllItems`, `this.setState({ obj })` is equivalent to `this.setState({ obj: obj })`. This is almost certainly not what you intend.

Comment: Add the end of submitItem you are doing: `then(this.pullAllItems('categories')`, shouldn't this be : `then(() => this.pullAllItems('categories'))`? Otherwise you're fetching directly without waiting for the promise.

Comment: Additionally, in `submitAllItems()`, `then(this.pullAllItems(...))` is called immediately. I assume you want to defer the call until after the `fetch()` completes. You want to do `fetch(...).then(() => this.pullAllItems())`.

Comment: Oh lord, you're both very right.  Changed to call pullAllItems after promise is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would want to do `this.setState(obj)` so that they dynamic key gets merged in to the state.